# Way to check timstamp of a particular record in SYBASE ASE

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Is there any way to view timestamp of a particular record in a table if we dont have any dedicated timestamp or date column for that table.

Comment: Hi, if you found my answer helpful, please upvote and/or accept my answer.  For more information on accepting answers, please see the page here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

No.  While there may be a timestamp value associated with record, it is used by ASE for transaction logging.  `timestamp` does not convert to a meaningful `datetime` value.